# Javascript - Trying to randomly pick from an array and populate inner HTML based off what was picked - Not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var enemyPokemon = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"];
var playerPokemon = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"];

// Randomly pick Pokemon from Enemy Pokemon List

var enemyChosenPokemon = 
enemyPokemon[Math.floor(Math.random()*enemyPokemon.length)];

console.log(enemyChosenPokemon);

// Populate Enemy Information with computer picked Pokemon

// Set Enemy Pokemon Name
    if (enemyChosenPokemon == "Charmander"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = "Charmander";
    } else if (enemyChosenPokemon == "Bulbasaur"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = "Bulbasaur";
    } else if (enemyChosenPokemon == "Squirtle"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = "Squirtle";
    };
```

My HTML is basically this:

`<div class="enemy-pokemon-name">Enemy Pokemon</div>`

I want the name "Enemy Pokemon" to be replaced with the correct name dependent of what Pokemon is randomly picked from the list of 3 but I can't seem to get the inner HTML to change.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: .getElementsByClassName returns an array.So either change the class to an ID, or call it as document.getElementsByClassName("enemy-pokemon-name")[0]

Comment: @MarcRDesign Do mark the solution that best solves your problem as the right answer by clicking the grey tick mark beside the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Change the class to ID on the div:

```
<div id="enemy-pokemon-name">Enemy Pokemon</div>
```

and your JS will be like this:

```
document.getElementById("enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = "Charmander";
```

As Emiel said though, it would be more efficient to add a var like this:

```
var enemyElement = document.getElementById("enemy-pokemon-name");
```

and then use it like this:

```
enemyElement.innerHTML = "Charmander";
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to use class name instead of an id and only have one html element with the class name `enemy-pokemon-name`, you can just use the [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method to target the div and since your result and the array element text content is the same, you can directly render the result on the div like this:

```
var enemyPokemon = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"];
var playerPokemon = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"];
document.querySelector(".enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = enemyPokemon[Math.floor(Math.random()*enemyPokemon.length)];
```

The same above code could be used if you changed your class name to an id too by simply targeting `#enemy-pokemon-name` instead of `.enemy-pokemon-name` in the querySelector.

Check and run the following Code Snippet or open this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/xt0rujmo/) link for a practical example of the above code:

```js
var enemyPokemon = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"];
var playerPokemon = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"];
document.querySelector(".enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = enemyPokemon[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemyPokemon.length)];
```

```html
<div class="enemy-pokemon-name">Enemy Pokemon</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the class to ID and use getElementByID, or use the querySelector:

```
if (enemyChosenPokemon == "Charmander"){
        document.querySelector(".enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = "Charmander";
    } else if (enemyChosenPokemon == "Bulbasaur"){
        document.querySelector(".enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = "Bulbasaur";
    } else if (enemyChosenPokemon == "Squirtle"){
        document.querySelector(".enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = "Squirtle";
    };
```

Comment: Good answer. This will be even better by storing the `document.querySelector(".enemy-pokemon-name")` in a variable so that the `querySelector` only has to be executed once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I seem to get a TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null when I do this though.

Comment: @MarcRDesign have you changed your `<div class="enemy-pokemon-name">` to `<div id="enemy-pokemon-name">` as well?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I tried the method of changing the div class to an ID and using getElementById but for some reason it's returning a null error.

Comment: @MarcRDesign is your `script` tag before or after the elements you are trying to select in your HTML?

Comment: @EmielZurrbier oh my gosh you solved it! I am a moron - my HTML wasn't even in the body!

Comment: @MarcRDesign ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to make randomness a bit more readable:

```js
var enemyPokemon = ["Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"];
document.querySelector(".enemy-pokemon-name").innerHTML = rando(enemyPokemon).value;
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<div class="enemy-pokemon-name">Enemy Pokemon</div>
```